# JQuery hide column from specific table

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html-table

I read an article of how to hide a column using JQuery. That has got me to use the below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%= btnHideColumn.ClientID %>').click(function () {
            $('td:nth-child(1)').hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Although this works I would eventually have two tables under this AJAX Accordion Pane. How could I target a certain table and hide the column as required?

My table is generated in code behind. So not sure which properties would need to be filled beforehand.

Comment: Use separate ID`s for the tables, respectively columns

Comment: Give each table an unique class and tell your function which table it should take by inserting that unique class name into your jquery selector

Comment: Thanks everyone however im new with JQuery and prefer examples of what i would need to do. Please keep in mind my table is created in code behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also specify table in your cell selector, e.g.:

```
$('table:eq(0) td:nth-child(1)').hide(); // table:eq(0) selects first table
```

or

```
$('table#list td:nth-child(1)').hide(); // table#list selects table with id="list"
```

Comment: Using the `this` word is much more efficient

Comment: This partially works. By partial what i mean is if i add two tables manually to the accordian pane then the table column disappears as expected. When i target the table created in code behind the entire table disappears?

Comment: @Jupiter, it is very strange. Could you show structure of your pane content with both generated tables?

Comment: Before i post my code i thought to mention that the code that creates the table (in code behind) is a simple for each loop and then i add it to the panel (i.e. panel1.Add.Controls(Tabl)). The structure under the inline code in short is update panel > PANEL > Accordian > Pane where PANEL is the panel i add the table too. The table once displayed is not listed under view source strangely.

Comment: It's possible to copy resulting structure of page fragment in all major browsers. _Resulting_ means _after all initial scripts are run_.

Comment: It doesnt show alot (to me anyway), the table is not listed although viewable in the browser. If you prefer me to send you the entire project please advise

div id="MainContent_Test"></div><input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$apNoOfCustomers_content$btnHideColumns" value="Hide Columns" id="MainContent_btnHideColumns" class="defButton" />
   </td>
    </tr>
      </table>
        </div></div></div></div></div>

Comment: The last bit that i couldnt add to the previous reply:

<div style="margin: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-size: small; color: Red;"><div id="MainContent_ValidationSummary1" style="display:none;">
</div></div>
            <div id="MainContent_pnlNumbers">
 <p><span id="MainContent_Label1">Label</span>
</p></div></div></div>
<div class="clear">
</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>

Comment: Which line are you referring to? As it could be a typo?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 scenarios here:

1. If you want the exact same behaviour on the 2 tables then give them both the same class and then use the word `this` inside the click function:

   ```
   <table class="data">....

   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('.data').click(function () {
           $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').hide();
       });
   });
   ```
2. If you need a different behaviour, give each of them a different id and bind a different click event to each.